# Интеграционный тест Mediatr?

Tags: c#, юнит-тесты, asp.net-core-mvc, cqrs, mediatr

У меня есть некоторый обработчик входного запроса:

- читает данные о объекте из базы данных
- в прочитанных данных проверяет поле OwnerId сравнивая его с информацией о пользователе, создавшем запрос по определённым правилам. В частности, если объект содержится в публичной базе (OwnerId == 0), то можно видеть всем, иначе нужно чтобы OwnerId совпадал с CurrentUserId

В принципе, у меня всё работает, достаточно красиво разделены обязанности по разным классам о самом чтении (находится в Handler) и проверке видимости (находится в PostHandler)

У меня вопрос по покрытию этого тестами: я быстро написал юнит тесты на сам Handler и на PostHandler, но не понимаю, как мне написать интеграционные сценарии, как мне это протестировать и насколько вообще это нужно.

У меня есть определённые сомнения, что это прям так необходимо. Я где-то слышал советы в духе "не тестируйте чтение-запись в базу, потому что майкрософт уже покрыла тестами EF, так что вы делаете лишнюю работу". Тут с одной стороны, у меня есть аргумент "за" то, чтобы не писать: фактически за корректную работу pipeline'ов отвечает сам Mediatr (что после Handler'а запустятся PostHandler'ы) и я могу рассчитывать на то, что пока я не обновлю нугеты на версию с breaking changes всё будет работать как задумывалось.
С другой стороны, сколько ни читай release notes, вот как раз хочется как раз соломку и подстелить и видеть, поломает ли обновление работу приложения или нет. Тем более юнит-тесты написаны, значит пора двигаться дальше по пирамиде тестирования.

Но допустим, решено, что пора писать более общие тесты. Как это правильно сделать технически?

Вот мои классы для конкретики, с некоторыми упрощениями.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Запрос:

```
public class Query : IRequest<Result>
{
    public Query(int personId, int currentUserId)
    {
        this.PersonId = personId;
        this.CurrentUserId = currentUserId;
    }

    public int PersonId { get; }

    public int CurrentUserId { get; }
}
```

Ответ:

```
public class Result
{
    public Result(PersonDto person)
    {
        this.Person = person;
    }

    public PersonDto Person { get; }
}
```

Обработчик:

```
public class Handler : BaseHandler, IRequestHandler<Query, Result>
{
    public Handler(ApplicationDbContext applicationDbContext)
        : base(applicationDbContext)
    {
    }

    public async Task<Result> Handle(Query request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        const string query = @"
            SELECT
                  P.Id
                , P.OwnerId
                , P.FirstName
                , P.LastName
            FROM dbo.Persons P
            WHERE 1 = 1
                AND P.Id = @personId
        ";

        var parameters = new
        {
            @currentUserId = request.CurrentUserId,
            @personId = request.PersonId,
        };

        var person = await this.Db.QueryFirstOrDefaultAsync<PersonDto>(new CommandDefinition(query, parameters, cancellationToken: cancellationToken));

        return new Result(person);
    }
}
```

Проверка бизнес-правил:

```
public class PostHandler : IRequestPostProcessor<Query, Result>
{
    public Task Process(Query request, Result response, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (VisibleForEveryone(response.Person))
            return Task.CompletedTask;

        if (response.Person.OwnerId != request.CurrentUserId)
            throw new SecurityException($"Current user id={request.CurrentUserId} is not an owner for person id={request.PersonId}.");

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Конкретные юнит-тесты приводить не буду, для постобработчика они тривиальны, а для обработчика лезут в базу (и я намучавшись с чрезмерными упрощениями InMemory прям реальную БД на `localdb\mssqllocaldb` стал подымать, ужас и медленно, но куда деваться). В общем, юниты покрыты достаточно, а вот где (на каком уровне приложения) и как проверять, что создав запрос и отправив его в Mediatr будет вызван не просто Handler, но и обязательно вызовется PostHandler.

Собственно, я вижу две точки, которые влияют на это поведение:

1. Сам код библиотеки Mediatr https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/blob/master/src/MediatR/Pipeline/RequestPostProcessorBehavior.cs
2. Код бутстрапера для asp.net-mvc https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection который гарантирует что соберёт типовой эталонный загрузчик Mediatr чтобы не регистрировать самостоятельно портянку в Startup.cs

Поэтому по идее ничто не мешает мне сделать webapi проект, который подключит проект слоя application таким образом, что классы application слоя не соберутся в нужный мне pipeline, а будут какие-то баги.

Получается, что уровень проекта на котором проверять подобные связки -- самый нижний в иерархии проектов, прямо на уровне Webapi.Test проверять подобное, верно?

С другой стороны хотя кажется что самый правильный тест -- это создать реальный экземпляр Mediatr, кинуть в него запрос и проверять, что отработало, а что нет. Но нет понимания как замокать Handler и как замокать PostHandler, т.к. мне по сути нужно выполнить проверку pipeline, а конкретная реализация уже покрыта отдельно.

Поэтому возможно это вопрос на понимание как конкретно устроить моки для библиотеки Mediatr (у меня nUnit+FakeItEasy, но мне главное понять принцип, поэтому в ответе подойдёт любой фреймворк тестирования, некритично). А возможно и нет, тут не обойтись без более широкого ответа на концептуальном уровне. В общем, если у кого есть мысли по этой теме -- пишите, буду рад мнениям.

Comment: Если вы пишете интеграционный тест, то зачем что то мокать? Я бы так и поступил - сделал бы себе тестовую бд, поднял бы в тесте свой вебсайт и напрямую бы вызывал контроллеры.

Comment: @tym32167 А, вот, я понял что хотел и забыл, не дописал в вопрос. Я думал "понизить градус" и провести тестирование этажом ниже, но для этого видимо нужно вынести настройки Mediatr из Startup.cs в проект Application ([дока](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/platform-specific-configuration?view=aspnetcore-2.2), [примеры](https://github.com/search?l=C%23&q=HostingStartupLibrary&type=Code))

Answer (score 0):

В итоге я остановился на следующем решении:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В проекте Application появился конфигуратор для Mediatr:

```
public static class MediatrConfiguration
{
    public static void Configure(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMediatR(typeof(Values.GetList.Query).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);
    }
}
```

И соответственно если раньше проект зависел только от медиатора:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="MediatR" Version="7.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

, то сейчас добавилась явная зависимость от штатного бутстрапера

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="MediatR" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="MediatR.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="7.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

и через него одна неявная — от выбранного DI движка (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions)

Этот конфигуратор используется и в Startup.cs

```
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        MediatrConfiguration.Configure(services);
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
    }
```

и при настройке интеграционных тестов:

```
public class TestBase
{
    protected IMediator GetMediator()
    {
        var services = new ServiceCollection();

        MediatrConfiguration.Configure(services);

        var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

        var mediator = provider.GetService<IMediator>();

        return mediator;
    }
}
```

Технически, можно было бы вынести в отдельный проект конфигурирование mediatr (на случай замены DI движка), но я решил что это мне не понадобится (или она и так тривиальна), архитектурную границу я вполне и так вижу, а вот иметь в проекте Application уже корректно собранные в пайплайны классы мне очень удобно и понятно (проекты Application.UnitTests и Application.IntegrationTests разделены только в демо-приложении, в реальном это один проект Application.Tests)

Итого, интеграционные тесты с mediatr получились примерно такого вида:

```
/// <summary>
/// Tests for both <see cref="Handler"/>, <see cref="PreHandler"/> and <see cref="PostHandler"/>
/// </summary>
public class IntegrationTest : TestBase
{
    [Test]
    public void ZeroValue_Throws()
    {
        var mediatr = GetMediator();
        var id = 0;
        var query = new Query(id);

        var ex = Assert.ThrowsAsync<Exception>(async () => await mediatr.Send(query));
        StringAssert.AreEqualIgnoringCase("Empty request.", ex.Message);
    }
    ...
}
```